# Grails: good tutorial/explanation for non-trivial testing

Tags: testing, grails, automated-tests

I am working on a super sweet Grails project.

I get simple tests, like having some made-up data objects to mess with validators, but what about when I have 30 different domain-classes, only 1 is modified by users - the rest by services in both an event-driven and periodic fashion... what can I even test for?

Is there some discussion on testing theory I should read?  Am I totally missing it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Chapter 7 of [Grails in Action](http://www.manning.com/gsmith/) is what explained it best to me.